# How do I access static variables in an enum class without a class instance?

Tags: java, generics, static, enums, field

I have some code that processes fixed length data records.  I've defined the record structures using java enums.  I've boiled it down the the simplest example possible to illustrate the hoops that I currently have to jump through to get access to a static variable inside the enum.  Is there a better way to get at this variable that I'm overlooking?  If you compile and run the code, it converts each string into an XML chunk.  I've done the XML manually so that the example is simpler, but my real code uses Java DOM.

**EDIT: I've updated the code to a more complete example that I think better shows what I'm trying to do.**

```
class EnumTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println( parse("ABC", RecordType1.class) );
        System.out.println( parse("ABCDEF", RecordType2.class) );
    }

    private interface RecordLayout {
        public int length();
    }

    private enum RecordType1 implements RecordLayout {
        FIELD1      (2),
        FIELD2      (1),
        ;
        private int length;
        private RecordType1(int length) { this.length = length; }
        public int length() { return length; }

        public static int RECORD_LEN = 3;
    }

    private enum RecordType2 implements RecordLayout {
        FIELD1      (5),
        FIELD2      (1),
        ;
        private int length;
        private RecordType2(int length) { this.length = length; }
        public int length() { return length; }

        public static int RECORD_LEN = 6;
    }

    private static <E extends Enum<E> & RecordLayout> String parse(String data, Class<E> record) {

        // ugly hack to get at RECORD_LEN...
        int len = 0;
        try {
            len = record.getField("RECORD_LEN").getInt(record);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

        String results = "<RECORD length=\"" + len +  "\">\n";
        int curPos = 0;
        for (E field: record.getEnumConstants()) {
            int endPos = curPos + field.length();
            results += "  <" + field.toString() + ">"
                    + data.substring(curPos, endPos)
                    + "</" + field.toString() + ">\n";
            curPos = endPos;
        }
        results += "</RECORD>\n";
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't see a reason for them to be static, they can be instance level and final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code in Java 8?

```
    // Java 8
public class EnumTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(parse("ABC", RecordType1.class));
        System.out.println(parse("ABCDEF", RecordType2.class));
    }

    private interface RecordLayout {
        public int length();

        public static <E extends Enum<E> & RecordLayout> int getTotalLength(Class<E> e) {
            int total = 0;
            for (E e1 : e.getEnumConstants()) {
                total += e1.length();
            }
            return total;
        }
    }

    private enum RecordType1 implements RecordLayout {
        FIELD1(2),
        FIELD2(1),;
        private int length;

        private RecordType1(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }

        public int length() {
            return length;
        }
    }

    private enum RecordType2 implements RecordLayout {
        FIELD1(5),
        FIELD2(1),;
        private int length;

        private RecordType2(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }

        public int length() {
            return length;
        }
    }

    private static <E extends Enum<E> & RecordLayout> String parse(String data, Class<E> record) {
        int len = RecordLayout.getTotalLength(record);
        String results = "<RECORD length=\"" + len + "\">\n";
        int curPos = 0;
        for (E field : record.getEnumConstants()) {
            int endPos = curPos + field.length();
            results += "  <" + field.toString() + ">"
                    + data.substring(curPos, endPos)
                    + "</" + field.toString() + ">\n";
            curPos = endPos;
        }
        results += "</RECORD>\n";
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `RecordType1.LEN` not work?

I don't have a Java environment at hand right now, so I'm preparing to wipe egg from my face, but since `enum Foo` is equivalent to `class Foo extends Enum<Foo>` I cannot see why you can't just access the static members in the standard way.

Edit: if you want to access static members dynamically, then this isn't going to work as you **have** to access static members based on the class rather than the instance, that's the point.  You should probably do something like this instead, since if the behaviour changes depending on the subtype of the instance, that's *exactly* the kind of thing an interface is for:

```
class EnumTest
{  

    private interface RecordLayout {
        public int length();
        public int staticLength(); // give this a more meaningful name
    }

    private enum RecordType1 implements RecordLayout {
        ...

        public static int LEN = 3;
        public int staticLength() {
            return LEN;
        }
    }

    private enum RecordType2 implements RecordLayout {
        ...

        public static int LEN = 5;
        public int staticLength() {
            return LEN;
        }
    }

    ...

    private static String parse(String data, RecordLayout record) {
        int len = record.getStaticLength();
        System.out.println(len);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The parse method is meant to be generic so that it can process any enum that implements the RecordLayout interface.  In my actual code, there are many such enums.  If I put RecordType1.LEN in my parse method, then it would be wrong if I called it with RecordType2.class as a parameter.

Comment: In that case, you have to add another method to the `RecordLayout` interface, since the generic type parameters are only little more than syntactic sugar at compile time.

At run time, they disappear in almost all cases.

Comment: Then the problem is that you are passing in a class (record) rather than an instance of record.  If you passed in an instance of record you could call: record.length().

Comment: If there is something you need to access from the RecordLayout interface, then you need to add it to the RecordLayout interface.

Comment: @Roland
I've tried adding another method to the RecordLayout interface.  The problem is that I can't call a static method because I don't have a class instance.  So unless I'm missing something, that won't work either.

Comment: @krick - then you're misunderstanding the point of static fields.  If you want dynamic dispatch, then you'll need to make it an instance-level method (ideally on the RecordLayout interface) and have the different implementations of this method point to the relevant static fields.  Static fields are when you want to refer to something... well, statically, as in "always the same".

Comment: @Andrzej - I fully understand the point of static fields. If you try it yourself, I think you'll find that it doesn't work the way you think in my code.  I've tried adding a method to the interface and implementing it in each enum.  I just can't access it from "record".

Comment: At run time, your `parse` method doesn't know whether it was "generified" with `RecordLayout1` or `RecordLayout2`, because at that time, the generic types are all *erased*. It's like that in Java.

Comment: Andrzej is right you are not using the static qualifier correctly, I don't see any reason to make that static. And I don't see any reason to pass in a Class instead of an instance of the Enum.

Comment: I just put a more complete example up there because I don't think I'm fully explaining what I'm trying to do.  I want to be able to call a parse method and pass a string and a layout, and have the method carve up the string into the individual fields.  It works great, except the part where I get the RECORD_LEN is kind of hacky.  I just thought there was a better way that I was missing.

Comment: @krick: Maybe each RecordType should do it's own parsing. I think you can find an easier, more OO way to do what you're trying if you look at the problem from a different perspective.  If something is this hard to do, it's usually a sign that your approach is not correct.

Comment: I just figured out that I can pass the length to the parse method as a parameter using RecordLayout1.RECORD_LEN at the spot where I call parse(). I just can't get at it inside the method without a lot of work.  I guess an extra parameter or two won't kill me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are inside the `EnumTest` class, you can access the `LEN` field by simply writing:

```
int len = RecordType1.LEN;
```

From the outside, it's still difficult.